# Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing plugin net.rim.tools.ajde android

Tags: android, android-install-apk

Any one please help me. I already have android studio 2.2 and i uninstalled android studio and again downloaded new version of android studio from developer site.  when i wanna open the project it is showing a popup like 
Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing plugin net.rim.tools.ajde.
Please any one help me.

Answer (score 3):

Clear the file in `C:\Users\lianjia\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\config\plugins` and then restart the IDE.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the BlackBerry plugin for Android Studio (net.rim.tools.ajde)

Uninstall it or deselect it in AS from

> File > Settings > Plugins

Now, the problem is how to run BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Studio in AS > 3.0